# Beginner: IF statement/PHP/HTML issue

Tags: php, html

I do apologise in advance for my lack of knowledge in PHP and HTML. I have scoured the internet for 3/4 days trying to create what is probably a simple system. I need the user to enter a digit before the next page is loaded. I have an IF statement on my page. 
1.php

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="container">
<div id="authorise">
<form action="2.php" method="post">
<!--Product Comment Box--><br>
<p>Please enter your 4<br> digit authorisation code:<br> <br>
<input type="text" name="digits" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

2.php

```
<?php
  if ($_POST['digits'] === '210392') 
  {echo 'https://www.facebook.com/'
 ?>
```

But I need a form first which the user would input the code '210392' and press submit. Then the if statement can take place. I know how to do a form but dont know how to assign that form a variable name 'digits'. All help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post the code for form and what you have tried so far. The code that you posted does not help much by itself and it is possible that some other part of the code might be giving you problem.

Comment: `if ($digits == '210392';` this is not correct, last `;` should be a `)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="check.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="digits" />
<input type="submit" value="click here" />
</form>

//in check.php 

if (isset($_POST['digits']) and $_POST['digits'] == 12345){
header("Location: http://google.com");
} 
else {
echo " error !!";
}
```

study html from w3school
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

and php 
http://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 4):

A basic form:

```
<form action="your_file.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="digits" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Then in `your_file.php`:

```
<?php
  if ($_POST['digits'] === '210392') {
  // etc.
```

`$_POST` is a superglobal array that has all data POSTed to your script.  `digits` in this case is an index in that array.  It comes from the name of the input field.

Comment: I'd add a button as well.

Comment: @TimWolla Good call.  :-D

Comment: I'll give that a whirl and report back. Thanks

Comment: <?php
  if ($_POST['digits'] === '210392') 
  {echo 'https://www.facebook.com/'
 ?>

Tried that it doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create an input with the very important name attribute which you'll use later.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="password" name="mypassword" />
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
//Post method access with $_POST variable:
if ($_POST['mypassword'] == 'my-password') { //Oh, you should probably use SSH and hash the password
    //Hooray!
}
```

Comment: A hash is not encryption, and that hash shouldn't be done client-side anyway.

Comment: @Brad Sorry, got 2 concepts confused. And typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form action="https://scm-intranet.tees.ac.uk/users/l1071039/bobbin/admin.php" method="post">
      Password : <input type="password" name="pwd" />
      <input type="submit" name="send">
    </form>

    // admin.php
    <?php 
    if( isset($_POST['pwd']) ){
        $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Jonty is trying to handle this with PHP, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echo, use header.

```
   <?php
   if ($_POST['digits'] === '210392') 
   {
   header (loaction:https://www.facebook.com/);
   }
   ?>
```